# C# WSDL - Create several linked objects

Tags: soap-api, lookup, account, wsdl, enterprise-wsdl

I'm working with the enterprise WSDL on a Salesforce org that has lots of objects that use the IDs from other objects to link them using a lookup relationship.

Currently, I'm trying to create an account and create an asset that has the `accountId` on it.

The implementation is below with some fields omitted

---

```
          var consumer = new Account()
            {
                Salutation = "Mr",
                FirstName = "Tom",
                LastName = "Finley",
                House_Number__c = "33"
            };

            var site = new Asset()
            {
                Name = "placeholderValueThatGetsOverwritten",
                AccountId = consumer.Id,
                RecordTypeId = "0121j000000rYajAAE",
                Street_1__c = "33",
            };

            _service.AllOrNoneHeaderValue = new AllOrNoneHeader { allOrNone = true };

            var objectsToCreate = new sObject[] { consumer, site };

            var results = _service.create(objectsToCreate);
```

This creates the objects as expected, however, the site `AccountId` is set to null, as you'd expect because I'm declaring it before its created.

Is there any way to link the objects upon creation? It looks like this should work from here; https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hbQGAAY

Comment: You will need to use external IDs to make that happen. Please see this link for more details, section create and foreign keys.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_create.htm

Comment: Is there a way to do this without editing the objects and adding an external ID? @manjit5190

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to make 2 calls then, one to create account, get the response and then the asset. Another way would be use REST API composite call, which doesn't requires external IDs but it does work on WSDL.

Comment: Did you mean which doesn't work on the WSDL? Is there a way to use AllOrNone when creating them individually? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: 1. I meant the composite call is REST API call so that won't work with WSDL and needs a HTTP fallout to be made. 2. No, all or none does not work like that, it works for a single transaction. In you case there will be two transactions one for account, one for asset